# Approximate Bayesian computation for comparing parameters affect on a response variable

Tags: approximate-bayesian-computation, approximate-inference

I'm not sure I understand this method perfectly so please correct me if I'm wrong. From my understanding Approximate Bayesian Computation allows you to perform likelihood free inference by re-simulating the data to get estimates of parameters of interest like the mean and variance of a group. It's often used in complex models where calculating the likelihood is intractable (I'm just paraphrasing from what I've read; I'm not sure why the likelihood if intractable for some of these models). What I'm trying to find out is could I apply ABC in such a way that I could make inferences similar to traditional regression approaches where I could see how some parameters (predictors) affect a response variable?

(I have multiple questions to ask about ABC that I'll update in the near future so apologies if it feels like I'm asking multiple questions in this post. If people have suggestions for changing the wording I'd gladly appreciate it)

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. To apply ABC you need (a) a fully specified model (b) a generative model from which you can generate new data (c) a prior distribution on the parameters of the model.